# Silent sms detection IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios6, sms, silent

Is it possible to detect a silent SMS in application?
I'm working on a project that registers users by SMS verification code (Phone number). The current  workflow in application is that the user writes his phone number and requests verification code. The server sends the verification code by SMS to the previously written phone number.
Now the part that I want to change is, instead of forcing the user to shut off my application and go to the SMS app to copy the verification code, then going back to my app and pasting the code and finally registering. I want to use some other way like: Server is sending a silent SMS, the application detects it, reads the verification code and verify the user.

Are there any ways to simplify the verification process for the user? It does not have to be a silent/stealth SMS

This app has >IOS6 requirements

Comment: I really think that the answer is NO. I think Apple does not allow you to interact on this level with the operating system.

Comment: No, unless you jailbreak.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and mark top answer, answers that have helped you. Others facing the same issue will want to know what solved your issue and those answering the questions appreciate the rep points. If no answer answered your question or need further details, leave a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to read an SMS with objective c, nor is it possible to send an SMS to an iOS device and not have the user alerted.

If you want to implement an "Enter you phone number to receive a code" system, you must have the user copy the code in.

This may be possible with a jailbreak, but can't confirm that. From an apple, and being approved by the appstore point of view. Big no no

Comment: is it already possible to detect and read silent SMS? Thanks

Comment: @andoni-da-silva there is no such thing as a silent SMS

Comment: Thanks Simon, just to confirm, from iOS we can not also read normal SMS content

Comment: @AndoniDaSilva To the best of my knowledge you can't, and will never be able to read SMS contents due to apples very public privacy stance. Apple uses some machine learning to try to spot one-time-passwords and allows those to be autofilled in textfields when setup correctly. That is the only thing i'm aware of. You can see a number of answers related to such here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187841/read-sms-message-in-ios