# I want to use or detect message present in Messages, in my iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, imessage

I am developing an iPhone app, for that I want to copy or detect message present in iMessage and use it in my App. I know iOS can't detect message data like Android because of privacy, is there any way to do it?
OR
Can I use iMessages Extension to use iMessage data in my iPhone app? How it can be implemented?
I did not understand how to get contents of message in my app without copy pasting it or manually entering it?

Comment: I hope that this is never possible, since it would be a huge privacy issue. So my guess is that you are out of luck.

Comment: It's not possible, and like @rckoenes says, I hope it's never possible.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your feedback, Is there any alternate option to do so? or User have to manually copy and paste the message.

Comment: If there was an alternative, then we wouldn't be telling you that's it's not possible... ;)

Comment: Yes thats right, Thank you. as @rckoenes says i am out of luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Silent sms detection IOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537376/silent-sms-detection-ios)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in iOS because of privacy maintained by Apple.