# Opening app from sms and getting the sms contents in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to build an iOS application. The basic premise is that the user receives an SMS which has a message, a link to the application, and other details. For example, the message might look like this:

```
Good morning! Kindly open the application: mylink://here
Additional Info: 123123
Additional Info: 321321
```

I know that if the user has installed my application, he or she will be able to click the `mylink://here` and it will open my application. [Answers in this question discuss said topic thoroughly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010915/open-app-from-sms-with-my-url-scheme-as-a-link) My concern mainly has something thing to do with fetching the additional information from the text message. My application will need the additional informations in the SMS and is there a way to fetch the additional information *without having to programmatically go through them in my application?*

Since the application is opened via SMS, is there a provision in iOS that provides your application, if opened by an SMS, with the raw SMS text?

I'm a bit new in iOS development and I'm mostly relying on what I am able to research online. As much as possible I do not want to fetch the SMSs (if iOS even allows that), find the one I'm looking for, then parse from there.

Comment: There's no way to get any SMS data at all (unless you use private APIs that would get your app rejected by Apple). Why not just pass all the info you may need in the URL?

Comment: How would I do that...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can't read or send sms messages... At all. That's a big no-no in standard iOS. However, you could pass some simplified info via url scheme. It could look something like this:

```
myappscheme://www.someurl.com?flag=true&myotherinfo=hi
```

You'll want to read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: Oh so it then works like the POST/GET url where parameters are the other information and then I'll just fetch them from my application..? I think this is a good solution for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry from Apple side but can't access these on a standard, non-jailbroken iPhone. You should file a bug with Apple, perhaps they'll improve SMS access in the future.

Not possible
Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/index.html

For SMS sending through application allowed but for accessing inbox for sms/email not allowed.

It is only possible when the phone is Jailbreaked. There are many tools to jailbreak your phone.

Once Jailbreaked, an application cal open the SQLite database at

/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db and read the message table.

It contains, the date/time at which the message was received, the sender/recipient phone number and even the clear text of the message.

Refer this Question to read content of sms: [Read SMS message in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187841/read-sms-message-in-ios)

Comment: Uh what. I don't think you understood my question. I'm asking if it's possible to fetch the other information from the sms that opened your application. I wasn't asking if it's possible to send sms through my application or how to jailbreak.