# Opening app from SMS like addresses open Plans or Doctolib

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to open my Application from a SMS like when I receive an address and when i tap on it, open Plans. I receive also a SMS from server with this : a.doctolib.fr/hnFZ8k5sr who opens directly the application Doctolib. Is somebody knows how to do that?
I saw the answer : [Opening app from sms and getting the sms contents in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298839/opening-app-from-sms-and-getting-the-sms-contents-in-ios) but when i look at my sms, it's ok, that's run... thanks by advance!

[Opening app from sms and getting the sms contents in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36298839/opening-app-from-sms-and-getting-the-sms-contents-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

You should be searching on how to open to your app from SMS using url scheme.

These links can help you:

- [Open app from SMS with my url scheme as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010915/open-app-from-sms-with-my-url-scheme-as-a-link)
- https://web.archive.org/web/20110222053023/http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Universal link, If the app is installed, app will be opened otherwise will continue to the browser.

**Steps to support universal links-**

1. Create your apple-app-site-association file(Suppose your universal link is www.abc.com/getapp and you want to redirect in your app from here).

   ```
   {
    "applinks": {
       "apps": [],
       "details": [
           {
               "appID": "9JA89QQLNQ.com.apple.wwdc", //9JA89QQLNQ is your team ID & com.apple.wwdc is your bundle id
               "paths": [ "/getapp"]
           }
       ]
     }
   }
   ```
2. Upload this file to the root directory of there server where www.abc.com is hosted(from where you need to redirect to your installed app).

e.g- Suppose you have to redirect from www.abc.com/getapp then you need to upload the apple-app-site-association file to the root directory where the www.abc.com is get hosted.

3. Validate at http://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/. If the file is valid then all checks would be green.
4. Now prepare your app to support universal links-

   a. Go to developer.apple.com and enable Associated Domains to your app ID.

   b. Select your target and turn on Associated Domains switch.

   c. Add `applinks:abc.com`.
   [image]

   d. Add `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` app delegate method so that your app can receive a link and handle it appropriately.

**Not getting callback to the app-**

1.When a user is browsing your website in Safari and they tap a universal link to a URL in the same domain as the current webpage, iOS respects the user’s most likely intent and opens the link in Safari. 
[image]

2.Copy and paste your universal link(`http(s)://www.abc.com/getapp`) to notes and tap on it. It your app can handle this link you will get the option `Open in "AppName"`.

**References-**

1. https://gist.github.com/anhar/6d50c023f442fb2437e1
2. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Hope it may help.

Comment: Please check and if this solution works for you then accept the answer. Or if you face any difficulty, feel free to ask.